# git ignore a directory not working

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore, git-status

so I created a new directory called "Repository" WITHOUT adding, committing, and pushing

I then added this to my .gitignore

```
/home/users/user/httpdocs/Repository/*
/home/users/user/httpdocs/Repository
```

I also did this

`cd /home/users/user/httpdocs/Repository`

`git update-index --assume-unchanged $(git ls-files | tr '\n' ' ')`

but then whenever I do git status the directory will still appear:

> ```
>  Untracked files:
> #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
> #
> #       Repository/
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
> ```

How do I get that directory disappear from git status accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your git repo is located in `/home/users/user/httpdocs`, your `.gitignore` should just need `Repository`. `.gitignore` paths are relative.